# MySql get first and last result from query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating some document records in a database, and each document can have multiple versions. Each new version is a new record in the database. To group the document versions together, I'm assigning them a shared unique id `groupId`.

What I'm trying to fetch from the database is the latest document version, but I also want the original document's created at date:

```
documents table
- id
- group_id
- version
- created_at
```

example records:

```
id: 1, group_id: 'xyz', version: 1, created_at: date
id: 2, group_id: 'xyz', version: 2, created_at: date
id: 3, group_id: 'xyz', version: 3, created_at: date
etc...
```

I was thinking of using either distinct or order by and then adding a limit 1 on the query to just get 1 result:

```
SELECT * FROM documents 
WHERE group_id='xyz'
ORDER BY 'created_at' DESC
LIMIT 1
```

but how can I also include the created_at date of the original document, in addition to (or instead of) the latest version's created_at date?

I know I can re-run the query with the `ORDER BY 'created_at' ASC LIMIT 1` but is there a way to do it all in 1 query?

Comment: Your `documents` and `versions` should be in separate tables, with a foreign key in the `versions` table pointing to the document ID.

Comment: @Zack do elaborate, why 'should' they be?

Comment: Not a computer right now, so can't type out a full answer. But your data should be properly normalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use sub-queries:

```
SELECT * FROM documents 
WHERE id in (
    select min(id) FROM documents WHERE group_id='xyz'
    union
    select max(id) FROM documents WHERE group_id='xyz'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a subquery to query the original's CREATED_AT could work:

```
select id, group_id, created_at, (select min(created_at) from documents d2 where 
d2.group_id = d.group_id)
from documents d
where group_id = 'xyz'
order by created_at desc
limit 1
```

Since the CREATED_AT date for the original document doesn't change, I might suggest de-normalizing that data and adding a new column ORIGINAL_CREATED_AT that is filled in for all new rows.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT MIN(created_at) AS date_created, MAX(created_at) AS date_updated, group_id FROM documents WHERE group_id = 'xyz' GROUP BY group_id`

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a single group, I would go for:

```
select lastd.*,
       (select min(d2.created_at)
        from documents d2
        where d2.group_id = d.group_id
       ) as first_created_at
from (select d.*
      from documents d
      where group_id = 'xyz'
      order by created_at desc
      limit 1
     ) lastd;
```

In particular, this can make use of an index on `documents(group_id, created_at)`.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select d.* 
from documents d inner join (
  select group_id, min(created_at) mindate, max(created_at) maxdate
  from documents
  group by group_id 
) g on d.group_id = g.group_id and (d.created_at in (g.mindate, g.maxdate))
```

gives all the rows containing the min and max `created_at` for each `group_id`. 
You can add any condition you need like:

```
where d.group_id = 'xyz'
```